# Inputing date using Selenium/Python does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to fill out a form using Selenium in Python. The text fields work correctly, but when I use send text to the date fields, it does not work correctly. It appears to input blank spaces.

Here is the code:

```
h_dob_field = firefox.find_element_by_id(
            'MainContent_txtHDateofBirth'
    ).send_keys('01012001')
```

The console log shows that this is being sent:

```
 2016-02-16 17:24:38,934 - DEBUG - POST http://127.0.0.1:45672/hub/session/283ad883-ac6a-4f25-b747-26f61cb897fc/element/{cc4f0cd1-ef8a-41f5-bf0e-615b6a970031}/value {"id": "{cc4f0cd1-ef8a-41f5-bf0e-615b6a970031}", "sessionId": "283ad883-ac6a-4f25-b747-26f61cb897fc", "value": ["2", "1", "3", "1", "9", "6", "2"]}
```

The html I'm targeting is:

```
<input class="" name="ctl00$MainContent$txtHDateofBirth" id="MainContent_txtHDateofBirth" type="text">
```

The page that I'm trying to input data to is [here](https://kvets.chfs.ky.gov/Divorce/Details.aspx).

I've read some other answers that said I should try to call the click() method. I did that, but it didn't have an effect. I'm using the firefox driver; Python 3.4, on Linux Mint, and it is the latest version of selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the request for when you fill out the form manually and write a [custom web request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) based on your findings.

Another option is to use the use the selenium IDE extension for Firefox ([link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/)) and use it record feature to record you steps and have it made for you.

Comment: I used the selenium IDE to record my steps. It had the value for the date as 01/01/2001. I changed the string I was sending using send_keys to include the slashes. Oddly, with this change, it will include the month and the year, but only put spaces for the days: 01/  /2001.

Comment: @jejy2343 that is indeed odd, but your problem is solved now right or?

Comment: No, it's still not working correctly. Selenium won't put all the date digits in reliably. The point of my code is to get a generated pdf from that website, but I think it's going to be simpler for me to just generate the pdf myself with reportlabs than it will be to figure out what's going wrong with using Selenium.